# How to I resolve GetFrameContext failed in Windbg

Tags: .net-4.0, windbg, stack-trace, crash-dumps

I'm debugging a .NET 4.0 web application using a full crash dump and Windbg. I seem able to get all the versions of everything to match up however when I try to get the managed stack trace of all the thread I get

OS Thread Id: 0x7cd4 (13)
Child SP IP       Call Site
GetFrameContext failed: 1

For all of my managed threads. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

I was also getting this error, but I noticed that running !DumpStack does give me a trace when !ClrStack does not.

According to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e79fb093-7fea-4b01-89a4-7d10c911bff6/what-is-clrclrsemaphorewait-?forum=clr) it could just be a thread that has been scheduled but is not running. In other words not necessarily a problem. I'm not sure why the  clrstack command doesn't work though, possibly an sos bug?

```
0:037> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x57cc (37)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
GetFrameContext failed: 1
0:037> !dumpstack
OS Thread Id: 0x57cc (37)
Child-SP         RetAddr          Call Site
000000000772f688 000007fefdb210dc ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
000000000772f690 000007fef5ca36ca KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
000000000772f730 000007fef5ca3a97 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0xaa
000000000772f7f0 000007fef5ca3c20 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0x140
000000000772f830 000007fef5cb21ff clr!ThreadpoolMgr::NewWorkerThreadStart+0x2a7
000000000772f8d0 000007fef5cb0582 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x3b
000000000772f970 00000000778d652d clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
000000000772fb30 0000000077b0c521 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
000000000772fb60 0000000000000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you trying to display the managed stack? You should be using sos or sosex (preferably sosex). Does `!sosex.mk` work for you?

Download sosex from [here](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV2NowAvailable.aspx).

If you are using windbg to debug .net, you want sosex to do it.

Comment: I think I used `.loadby sos clr`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing [Psscor4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21255) WinDbg extension? Here is some [very useful article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers.aspx) on how to do that.