# Windbg - !clrstack

Tags: windbg

I'm attempting to debug a manual dump file of a 64bit w3wp process with 64bit Windbg (Version 6.10). The dump was taken with taskmgr. I can't get anything from the !clrstack command. Here is what I'm getting:

```
!loadby sos clr

!runaway

User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
  17:cf4       0 days 5:37:42.455

~17s

ntdll!ZwDelayExecution+0xa:

00000000`776208fa c3 ret

!clrstack

GetFrameContext failed: 1
```

What is `GetFrameContext failed: 1`?

Comment: Type the command || to verify what kind of dump you have. For .NET applications, this needs to be "full memory user mini dump". Also, run !threads to give an overview of all of the managed threads. You're currently pointing to thread #17 (~17s), but it may not be a managed threads. For native threads, you can use the k command to view the stack.

Comment: @Dono: task manager creates full memory dumps. For unmanaged threads, !clrstack usually says "Unable to walk the managed stack.", not "GetFrameContext failed".

Comment: It seems you're not alone, but there's no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878112/how-to-i-resolve-getframecontext-failed-in-windbg

Comment: possible to make the dump available?

Answer (score 3):

Use !dumpstack command instead of !clrstack. It usually works.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the "native" call stack by doing "k" and see what that gets you. Sometimes, the stack isn't quite right and the !ClrStack extension is pretty sensitive.